# Derive from a generic class bothers designer

Tags: delphi

I have the following base class

```
TServiceSubModuleSkel<T: TObjectSkel> = class(TDataModule)
```

and a derived class

```
TFetchPersonList = class(TServiceSubModuleSkel<TPersonService>)
```

`TPersonService` derives from `TObjectSkel`.

In code everything works fine (it compiles and runs as expected). But it looks to me like the designer messes up everything: whenever I try to open the `TFetchPersonList` there is an error message at design time which says:

> "Error creating the formular: base class not found".

Also, opening the base class, which is itself being derived from `TDataModule` doesn't work: The following error message pops onto the screen three times:

> "Error in module ServiceSubModule: Declaration of class TServiceSubmodule is missing or erroneous"

Is this simply not possible or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you aren't doing anything wrong. The designer just doesn't support this.

Comment: That's a pity! By the way, the same applies for simple VCL actions, just the error is different. Did anyone try if this changed in RAD Studio 10 Seattle? If not and anyone reported this as a bug, please post the link so that I can vote for it.